# SQL How can I get a count of messages going out by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that sends out messages, I would like to get a total count of the messages that have been going out month by month over the last year . I am new to SQL so I am having trouble with it . I am using MSSQL 2012 this is my sql

```
SELECT sentDateTime, MessageID, status AS total, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), sentDateTime, 120) AS Month
FROM MessageTable
WHERE CAST(sentDateTime AS DATE) > '2017-04-01'
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), sentDateTime, 120), sentDateTime, MessageID, status
ORDER BY Month;
```

Comment: month(sentDateTime) will return the month number, select/group by that.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `month()` and `year()` functions are more convenient than `datepart()` for this purpose.

I would go for:

```
select year(sentDateTime) as yr, month(sentDateTime) as mon, count(*)
from MessageTable
where sentDateTime > '2017-04-01'
group by year(sentDateTime), month(sentDateTime)
order by min(sentDateTime);
```

Additional notes:

- Only include the columns in the `select` that you care about.  This would be the ones that define the month and the count.
- Only include the columns in the `group by` that you care about.  Every combination of the expressions in the `group by` found in the data define a column.
- There is no need to convert `sentDateTime` to a date explicitly for the comparison.
- The `order by` orders the results by time.  Using the `min()` is a nice convenience.
- Including the `year()` makes sure you don't make a mistake -- say by including data from 2018-04 with 2017-04.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- this selects the part of the date you are looking for, replace this with the date format you are using, this should give you what you are looking for
SELECT DATEPART(mm, GETDATE())

SELECT  COUNT(DATEPART(mm, sentDateTime)), MessageID, status
 From MessageTable where Cast(sentDateTime as date) > '2017-04-01'
 group by DATEPART(mm, sentDateTime), MessageID, status
 order by  DATEPART(mm, sentDateTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the month number of the `sentDateTime` with the function `DATEPART(MONTH, sentDateTime)`. The next select will also yield results if no message was sent for a particular month (`total = 0`).

```
;WITH PossibleMonths AS
(
    SELECT
        M.PossibleMonth
    FROM
        (VALUES 
            (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) M(PossibleMonth)
),
MonthTotals AS
(
    select  
        COUNT(1) AS Total,
        DATEPART(MONTH, sentDateTime) [Month] 
    From 
        MessageTable 
    where 
        Cast(sentDateTime as date) > '2017-04-01'
    group by 
        DATEPART(MONTH, sentDateTime)
)
SELECT
    P.PossibleMonth,
    Total = ISNULL(T.Total, 0)
FROM
    PossibleMonths AS P
    LEFT JOIN MonthTotals AS T ON P.PossibleMonth = T.Month
```